# Syntax highlight within a contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

Im trying to do some basic syntax highlighting within a contenteditable. It works and I can replace the word so that its wrapped in a  to style it, but any other text I type stays within those span tags.

Heres my code:

```
hiliter("Carrot", document.getElementById("myText"));
placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById("myText"));

function hiliter(word, element) {
  var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
  var repl = '<span style="color:red;">' + word + '</span>';
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
  console.log(element.innerHTML);
}

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
        && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
} else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
}
}
```

EDIT:  Heres a fiddle showing the issue. If you some text and the word 'test' into the box and click highlight It will highlight the word. But then after that any more text you type stays within those span tags instead of going after the  closing tag. You can verify by clicking the show html button.

https://jsfiddle.net/f3wmekLL/

Comment: I'd recommend adding your code into a fiddle in order to display the behavior you're explaining.

Comment: Thanks, I added a fiddle!

Comment: Whoops! thanks I added the link

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did is added an `input` event listener, which removes the highlight by replacing the `<span style="color:red;">` and `</span>` with empty string.

EDIT: Added a fix for Chrome. I modified the event listener to remove all highlights and re-highlight the words. Seems to fix the issue!

```js
function highlight(addEventLis) {
  hiliter("test", document.getElementById("textBox"), addEventLis);
  placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById("textBox"));
}

function showHTML() {
  alert(document.getElementById("textBox").innerHTML);
}

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
    typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
}

function hiliter(word, element, addEventLis) {
  var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
  var repl = '<span style="color:red;">' + word + '</span>';
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
  addEventLis && element.addEventListener("input", function remove() {
    removeHighlight();
    highlight(false);
    element.removeEventListener("input", remove);
  });

  //alert(element.innerHTML);
}

function removeHighlight(e) {
  let element = document.getElementById("textBox");
  let i = element.innerHTML.replaceAll('<span style="color:red;">', "");
  i = i.replaceAll('</span>', "");
  element.innerHTML = i;
  placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById("textBox"))
}
```

```css
#textBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<pre id="textBox" contenteditable="true"></pre>
<input type="button" value="Highlight word 'test'" onclick="highlight(true);" />
<input type="button" value="Show HTML" onclick="showHTML();" />
```